# Etymology of Demeter

Tags: etymology

Can the name of the Greek goddess Demeter come from PIE word for tamer, ***dōma̯tēr*** (especially given the Aeolic form of the goddess' name, Δωμάτηρ)? I am interested in both whether it is possible from sound change perspective and semantically.

Answer (score 5):

This etymology seems unlikely to me for several reasons:

1. A long o-grade in a Greek agent noun in -ter is at best unusual. I can't think of another such example, at any rate.
2. The -a- of the second syllable is long, as shown by Attic-Ionic Δημήτηρ. Of course, one could invoke folk etymology here, so this isn't conclusive.
3. The vowel in the first syllable in the more common forms of the name, Δημήτηρ / Δαμάτηρ, cannot come from PIE *ō.
4. It's pretty clear that Δαμάτηρ is a compound of Δα-μάτηρ, since the first element seems to occur in the name of Poseidon: *Potei-dāōn* 'husband of Da' (which he isn't in the traditional mythology, but seems to have formerly been).
5. It's not clear why an earth goddess should be named 'Tamer'.

Comment: Regarding the point 1 and 3, I actually do not know whether there was long o in PIE. Definitely the word for house had it, but in the word for tamer I speculated long o only based on the Aeolic form.

Comment: I have doubts Poseidon is related to Demeter, as Poseidon has a digamma in the middle as evident from Mycenean Greek, that is the original form is *Poteidawōn ("a" isn't long!) I'm not sure there are examples where -aw- collapses into -ā-, that is: *Dawmāter > *Dāmāter

Comment: @carsten The Mycenaean form, AFAIK, is Poseidaon, without a w; there is a Corinthian form of the name which has -w-, but this has to be innovative. The length of the -a- is shown by Homeric meter.

Comment: @TKR Hiatuses like "ao" usually appeared due to a loss of intervocalic -w-, -j- or -s-; Corinthian as you mention has -w-, how can this be a coincidence? As for length of -a-, I'm not sure

Comment: @carsten But -ao- would appear naturally if the derivation is Dā-ōn. Whatever the origin of the Corinthian -w- it can't be old, as the Mycenaean spellings show. Not sure what you mean about the length of -a-, since it's clearly long in Homer.

Comment: @TKR Can you provide native examples on -āō- without any original consonants in between?

Comment: @carsten Well, there's the first declension gen. pl. ending, which often appears as -āōn in Homer. In any case if there was a -w- in the name of Poseidon it would certainly be there in Mycenaean.

Comment: @TKR Myceneaen has PO-TE-DA-WO-NE (although it has forms without W as well). As for -āōn, I thought it stems from -āsōm, compare Latin -āsom > -ārum.

Comment: @carsten You're right that -āōn is from -āsōm, but that -s- was lost (or went to -h-) already before Proto-Greek. I don't know what the distribution is of the forms with and without -w- in Mycenaean. But there are lots of examples of phonetically excrescent -w- in dialectal inscriptions (spellings like *duwo*, *awutos*), which could easily be what's happening here. In any case there is a clear etymology for the form in -dāōn and none (AFAIK) for the form in -dāwōn.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably her name derives from PIE *dhǵhōm-. Kretschmer suggests that δᾶ (Δαματήρ) is a pre-Greek version of γη/γᾶ, but I tend to believe Heubeck's (1961) and others suggestion of an Indo-European root for 'earth'. Phrygian has

> **Γδ**αν μα

so that speaks too for a IE-root. Δᾶ seems to be the Doric version of γη/γᾶ.

Now in order to be cautious, we should remember that Phrygian could (or should) have shared substratum with Greek, hence that wouldn't eliminate Kretschmer's theory. However, I don't see much support for it by others.

Comment: Do u mean dhǵhem-?

Comment: What can u say about the etymology suggested in the question?

Comment: @Anixx: Yes, sorry! I will correct it. dhǵhem-, dhǵhom- is should be. It is written like that (with an "n") in Beekes etymological dictionary of Greek.

Comment: @Anixx: Let me have a closer look and I will get back to you later today. The meaning 'earth mother' feels natural in terms of Greek etymology, but I would like to examine what you suggest in depth.

Comment: This root gave Greek khamai, khthon. Isee no retention of d- in Greek.

Comment: @Anixx: Although, I am critical to Beekes suggestion, we should not underestimate the substratum influence on Greek, e.g γέφυρα ~ δέφυρα. See Beekes Pre-Greek (5.6) Velar/labial/dental: labio-velars.

Comment: @Anixx: There is an attic short form Δηώ for Demetra. Generally, I do not think that Demetra (vegetation, harvest etc goddess) would fit into the context you propose. It seems however there is a homonym Δωμάτηρ which means 'manager of the house' (See Mavridis 2009). I think we need to treat both words separately.

Comment: "Beekes suggests that δᾶ (Δαματήρ) is a pre-Greek (non-IE) version of γη/γᾶ," ... in fact Beekes explicitly rejects this suggestion.

Comment: @fdb: That was supposed to be Kretschmer. I have corrected it.

What Beekes said and it is relevant to the question is: "Derivation from *Δασ-μάτηρ < IE *dm̥s-, a supposed genitive of *dem- 'house' (cf. ►δεσπότης) by Ehrlich 1912: 62ff., should be rejected. "

Comment: You should edit the last paragraph as well.

Answer (score -1):

Both the name and the cult suggest a connection with the Sumerian god Dumuzi.
Another tradition that may be at the root of Demeter is that of Tiamat. This may also explain her link to Poseidon.